# C# Telerik Radgrid getting back the List of bound and modified Objects

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, asp.net-ajax, radgrid

I'm binding a List of my Objects of type "SomeInfo" to a RadGrid. After the User changed some of the Attributes I want to get back the modified List of the Objects. I can fetch every single cell and add them to new instances of my Objects and than add the Objects to a new List, but isn't there an easier way to do this? Binding the different attributes and everything works fine... In the `SomeInfo` class there are other attributes which I don't need to display in the `Radgrid`, but I need them in other places of Application.

```
public partial class ManageSomething : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private SWMKISAjaxDataService service = new SWMKISAjaxDataService();
        static List<SomeInfo> someInfos;     
        static int ID;
        static string csvFileName;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {        }

        protected void RadDropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, DropDownListEventArgs e)
        {
            ID = service.GetID(e.Text.ToString());
            CsvNameTextBox.Visible = true;
            ConfigButton.Visible = true;
        }

        private void RadGrid_BindData(string _csvFileName)
        {
            csvFileName = _csvFileName;
            SomeInfoWrapper myInfoWrapper = new SomeInfoWrapper();

            List<string> csvNames = myInfoWrapper.GetCsvFile(csvFileName);
            someInfos = mInfoWrapper.GetSomeInfoList(csvNames[1], ID);

            RadGrid1.Visible = true;
            RadGrid1.MasterTableView.Rebind();
            RadGrid1.DataSource = someInfos;
            RadGrid1.Rebind();
            SafeConfigButton.Visible = true;                        
        }

        protected void ConfigButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             RadGrid_BindData(CsvNameTextBox.Text.ToString());            
        }

        protected void SafeConfigButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Here I want to get back my modified List<SomeInfo> someInfos;
            // certainly I could fetch every cell of every Row or Column                    orsomething similar 
            // and set my objects and add them to a new List of my SomeInfoClass... but isnt there an easyer way? 
        }
    }
}

<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Root.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ManageSomething.aspx.cs" Inherits="Fuu.Admin.ManageSomething" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

<telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server">
</telerik:RadAjaxManager>

<telerik:RadDockLayout ID="RadDockLayout1" Runat="server">
    <telerik:RadDropDownList ID="IDDropDownList1" runat="server" 
        DataSourceID="EntityDataSource1" 
        OnSelectedIndexChanged="RadDropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" 
        DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Name" AutoPostBack="true">
    </telerik:RadDropDownList>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <telerik:RadTextBox ID="CsvNameTextBox" Runat="server" Label="File: " 
        Visible="False">
    </telerik:RadTextBox>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <telerik:RadButton ID="ConfigButton" runat="server" 
        OnClick="ConfigButton_Click" Text="Configurate" Visible="false">
    </telerik:RadButton>
</telerik:RadDockLayout>

<asp:EntityDataSource ID="EntityDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="name=MyEntities" DefaultContainerName="MyEntities" 
    EnableFlattening="False" EntitySetName="fuu" 
    Select="it.[Name], it.[ID]">
</asp:EntityDataSource>
<br />
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" Culture="de-DE" GroupPanelPosition="Top" 
    AllowAutomaticUpdates="True" AllowAutomaticInserts="True" 
    CellSpacing="-1" GridLines="Both" Visible="false">
    <ExportSettings>
        <Pdf PageWidth="">
        </Pdf>
    </ExportSettings>
    <MasterTableView AllowAutomaticInserts="False" DataKeyNames="">
        <Columns>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="csvName" 
                FilterControlAltText="nameColumn" HeaderText="Name" 
                UniqueName="nameColumn" ReadOnly="True">
                <ColumnValidationSettings>
                    <ModelErrorMessage Text="" />
                </ColumnValidationSettings>
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn DataField="visualize" 
                FilterControlAltText="checkboxColumn" HeaderText="visualize" 
                UniqueName="checkboxColumn">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" 
                        Checked='<%# Eval("visualize") %>'/>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn DataField="someType" 
                FilterControlAltText="someTypeColumn" HeaderText="type" 
                UniqueName="someTypColumn">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <telerik:RadDropDownList ID="RadDropDownList2" 
                        runat="server" DataSourceID="EntityDataSource2" 
                        DataTextField="name" DataValueField="name" 
                        SelectedValue='<%# Eval("someTyp.name") %>' >
                    </telerik:RadDropDownList>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
        </Columns>
    </MasterTableView>
    <ItemStyle ForeColor="Black" />
</telerik:RadGrid>
<telerik:RadButton ID="SafeConfigButton" runat="server" Text="safe config" 
    OnClick="SafeConfigButton_Click" Visible="false">
</telerik:RadButton>
<br />
<br />
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="EntityDataSource2" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="name=MyEntities" DefaultContainerName="MyEntities" 
    EnableFlattening="False" EntitySetName="SomeType" 
    Select="it.[name], it.[ID]" >
</asp:EntityDataSource>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: You can try casting the RadGrid's Datasource property to a list of your objects. It should be the up-to-date with user's modifications.

Comment: Had the same Idea yesterday, but it doesn't work  because Radgrid1.DataSource is null when I try to fetch and cast it ... -.-

Comment: Probably because you are trying this on another postback and the grid is not bound at that time.

Comment: do you have a Tip how I can avoid this ?

Comment: I am not sure I understand you, but if you want the updates from the user, you can use the grid's events as shown here: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/data-editing/manual-crud-operations/defaultcs.aspx